# QLPreviewcontroller toolbar issue in iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift3, toolbar, ios11, qlpreviewcontroller

I'm showing a local pdf file in Quicklook by presenting the QLPreviewController to the view controller

```
 func showFileWithPath(path: String){
    let quickLookController = QLPreviewController()
    quickLookController.dataSource = self
    quickLookController.delegate = self
    self.present(quickLookController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
    let pdfURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Mobile-Application", withExtension: "pdf", subdirectory: nil, localization: nil)
    return pdfURL! as QLPreviewItem
}
```

In iOS 10, quicklook works fine. But in ios 11 the toolbar is hidden and the toolbar buttons overlaps each other in the top left. It might be due to the toolbar absence.

[image]

Why is this happening? is there anyone seeing this issue in ios 11?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. You should definitely file a radar (ideally, with a demo project) via the developer portal and let Apple know.